# Extensionless URL for root and subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I has following htaccess rewrite rules which I wanted to changed to extensionless urls, its was working pretty well but there is a flaw when use it in sub-directory,

for example:

`www.domain.com/cp/login` doesn't show the page unless with extension `www.domain.com/cp/login.php`

`www.domain.com/contact_us` is working awesome.

Please help on rules below on how's extensionless working both on root and sub-directories?

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes

<Files *htaccess>
Deny from all
</Files>

<files page>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^cp/edit-agent/([^/\.]+)/?$ cp/edit-agent.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ agent.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/([^/\.]+)/?$ contact.php?a=$1 [L]

#rule to handle example.com/123/sys
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ project.php?a=$1&t=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT:**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes

<Files *htaccess>
Deny from all
</Files>

<files page>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^cp/edit-agent/([^/\.]+)/?$ cp/edit-agent.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ agent.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/([^/\.]+)/?$ contact.php?a=$1 [L]

#rule to handle example.com/123/sys
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ project.php?a=$1&t=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: is there an htaccess file in the cp directory? is there a directory called "login" in the cp directory?

Comment: @JonLin, no htaccess file in cp directory, login is a php file instead of folder.

Comment: @anubhava, it doesn't work, show 404

Comment: @anubhava, no htaccess reside in /cp/ folder

Comment: @anubhava, I comment out first top 3 `RewriteCond`, it show 500 internal server error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65256/discussion-between-anubhava-and-conmen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your .htaccess is in sub directory you need to use `RewriteBase` and use same `/_agent/` in front of `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` in your condition:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes

<Files *htaccess>
Deny from all
</Files>

<files page>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /_agent/

RewriteRule ^cp/edit-agent/([^/.]+)/?$ cp/edit-agent.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^contact/([^/.]+)/?$ contact.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]

#rule to handle example.com/123/sys
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ project.php?a=$1&t=$2 [L,QSA]

#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_agent/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ agent.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: in this case, does it means just to remove `RewriteBase /_agent/` if the whole site move to under root instead?

Comment: Yes correct and also remove `/_agent/` from `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_agent/$1\.php -f`